# How to interact with scene from layer in cocos2d-js?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-js

Hi guys im developing application and i wanna make pop up window when game is finished.[image: My app]

I wanna this result where background is not active and only button "restart" is clickable. I made this with 2 layers in one scene. In background layer is counter which is equal to 0 when game is finished

I need to add (or set visible) second(upper) layer when counter in background layer is 0 and don't know how to interact with scene from layer. Maybe is not smart solution but i got nothing for now. i Appreciate every advice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Made Global.js where was global boolean variable. Used Schedulerupdate() in scene and update function which checked that global variable. When counter in layer was 0 then changed global variable and scene react